# How to call C functions from ARM Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, gnu-assembler, cortex-a8

I'm writing code targeting ARM Cortex-A on Android devices (using GNU assembler and compiler), and I'm trying to interface between Assembly and C. In particular, I'm interested in calling functions written in C from Assembly. I tried many things, including the `.extern` directive, declaring C functions with `asm` and `__asm__` and so on, but none of them worked, so I'm looking for a minimal example of doing so. A reference to such example would be just as welcome.

Comment: @user606723 I was thinking of that, but C uses header files with function declarations for communication between different files. Wouldn't it be a completely different picture?

Comment: The compiler looks at the declaration of the function in the header file to compile the call.  You will need to do the same manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to read the ARM ARM and/or know the instruction set is all, normally you would want to do something like this

```
asm:

bl cfun

c:
void cfun ( void )
{

}
```

You can try this yourself. for gnu as and gcc this works just fine it should also work just fine if you use clang to get the c code to an object and gnu as for assembler.  Not sure what you are using.

The problem with the above is bl has a limited reach,

```
if ConditionPassed(cond) then
  if L == 1 then
    LR = address of the instruction after the branch instruction
    PC = PC + (SignExtend_30(signed_immed_24) << 2)
```

knowing that the bl instruction sets the link register to the instruction after the bl instruction, then if you read about the program counter register:

```
For an ARM instruction, the value read is the address of the instruction
plus 8 bytes. Bits [1:0] of this
value are always zero, because ARM instructions are always word-aligned.
```

so if you make your asm look like this:

```
mov lr,pc
ldr pc,=cfun
```

you get

```
d6008034:   e1a0e00f    mov lr, pc
d6008038:   e51ff000    ldr pc, [pc, #-0]   ; d6008040 
...
d6008040:   d60084c4    strle   r8, [r0], -r4, asr #9
```

The assembler will reserve a memory location, within reach of the ldr pc, instruction (if possible, otherwise generate an error) where it will place the full 32 bit address for the instruction.  the linker will later fill in this address with the external address.  that way you can reach any address in the address space.

if you dont want to play assembler games like that and want to be in control then you create the location to keep the address of the function and load it into the pc yourself:

```
    mov lr,pc
    ldr pc,cfun_addr

...

cfun_addr:
    .word cfun
```

compiled:

```
d6008034:   e1a0e00f    mov lr, pc
d6008038:   e51ff000    ldr pc, [pc, #-0]   ; d6008040 <cfun_addr>
...

d6008040 <cfun_addr>:
d6008040:   d60084c4    strle   r8, [r0], -r4, asr #9
```

Lastly if you want to move into the modern ARM world where ARM and thumb is mixed or can be (for example use bx lr instead of mov pc,lr) then you will want to use bx

```
    add lr,pc,#4
    ldr r1,cfun_addr
    bx r1
...

cfun_addr:
    .word cfun
```

of course you need another register to do that and remember to push and pop your link register and the other register before and after your call to C if you want to preserve them.

Comment: If you dont already know the calling conventions to know what registers are used for passing parameters for example, do one of two things, write some C code to call your function and disassemble to see what the compiler did.  the right answer is to look up the calling convention which others have pointed you to.

Comment: and you are correct I only showed the how to have ARM instructions call a function not to have thumb instructions call a C function I can edit the answer and show you how to do that as well...you mentioned a cortex A so I assume you are running arm instructions not thumb for the most part, taking advantage of the horsepower you have and not some bus constrained thing.

Comment: And as Brett mentioned relocatable objects can make it more complicated, you would need to make cfun_addr global, and whomever loads the relocatable object needs to modify cfun_addr before you use it.

Comment: Respect old_timer!

Answer (score 3):

**Minimal runnable armv7 example**

This question comes down "what is the ARM calling convention (AAPCS)". An example `a.S`:

```
/* Make the glibc symbols visible. */
.extern exit, puts
.data
    msg: .asciz "hello world"
.text
.global main
main:
    /* r0 is the first argument. */
    ldr r0, =msg
    bl puts
    mov r0, #0
    bl exit
```

Then on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf qemu-user-static
# Using GCC here instead of as + ld without arguments is needed
# because GCC knows where the C standard library is.
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o a.out a.S
qemu-arm-static -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf a.out
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

The easiest mistake to make in more complex examples is to forget that the stack must be 8 byte aligned. E.g., you want:

```
push {ip, lr}
```

instead of:

```
push {lr}
```

Example on GitHub with the boilerplate generalized: https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/82e915e1dfaebb80683a4fd7bba57b0aa99fda7f/c_from_arm.S

Comment: The OP wasn't asking how to ouput hello world.  He wanted to called a `C` function.

Comment: @SamHammamy isn't `puts` a C function? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need the specifications for the `armeabi-v7a`, describing the call stack, registers (callee vs. caller), etc. Then look at assembly output from compiled C code for syntax, etc. Things are more complicated when trying to call functions in shared libraries or relocatable objects.

Answer (score -4):

As Brett says, all you really have to do is put the right values in the right registers, and branch-with-link to the function's address. You'll need to be aware of what register the compiled function will overwrite, and which registers it will restore before it returns -- that's all written in the ABI documentation at infocentre.arm.com. You'll also need to make sure the stack register is set to what the compiler expects, and maybe other registers too (for PIC mode?)

But, do you really need to write the code in assembler files?

If you use the GCC "asm" feature then you can embed assembler fragments (as long as you like) into regular C functions, and drop back into C whenever it's more convenient.

There are cases where having C gubbins around won't do, but if you can call C functions I'm guessing you're not in those.

Come to that, why do you need to use assembler at all .... C is basically high-level assembler anyway?

Comment: Wow, that was unpopular ... but nobody says why?

Comment: Many reasons, but the simplest is that instead of answering the question, you told the OP not to use assembly, in effect telling them that their question is pointless. Not only if your reply a waste of time and space, and rude, it's also wrong. Assembly is often needed for writing startup boot code or to use niche hardware functions especially on microcontrollers. Or some people like it for it's computer science educational value.